# Decomposition subgroup of Cyclic Galois Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, galois-theory

My question: Say we have a cyclic Galois extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Denote the Galois group as $G$. If $H\leq G$, then does there exist a prime, $q$ in $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ such that the decomposition group $D \leq G$ of $p$ is equal to $H$?

Here are my thoughts so far: (I tried doing some specific examples and it seems that the answer to the question above should be yes, but I don't know exactly why!) Say we take a cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ where $\omega^{p} =1$. So this Galois extension has cyclic Galois group of order $p-1$. Furthermore, we know that if $q\neq p$, then $e=1$ and $f = $inf{$j\in \mathbb{N} | q^{j} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$)}. Thus, for this specific type of extension, the question boils down to: if $f|p-1$, does there exist a prime $q$ such that the inertial degree is $f$. My intuition says yes. Help?

Comment: This follows from (but is much weaker than) Chebotarev density.